# Solving Linear Equations over $Z_q$

Tags: linear-equations

Suppose we are given a linear equation $Ax = b$, where $A \in Z_{q}^{m \times n}$ and $b \in Z_{q}^{m}$.

Note that $q$ is NOT necessarily a prime here. I wonder whether the following can be done in $poly(n, m ,q)$ time:

1. Check whether there exists $x \in Z_{q}^{n}$ such that $Ax = b$.
2. Suppose there exists $x$ such that $Ax = b$, find such $x$.

Thanks.

Comment: This [paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~arkadev/singleLayer2G.pdf) by Arkadev Chattopadhyay and Avi Widgerson may be relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is well known it can be done by diagonalizing the matrix using row *and* column operations. An outline of the procedure is given in the paper [The Complexity of Solving Equations over Finite Groups](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/inco.2002.3173) by Goldmann and Russell.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) It appears that their proof relies on the fact that Abelian group decomposition can be found efficiently, I wonder whether this is indeed the case.